# UWP push notifications without WNS

Tags: push-notification, uwp, wns

Is there any way for a LoB UWP app to receive push notifications *without* using WNS or being registered to the Store, e.g., from a local server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup socket connection between your application and server side and handle any information in foreground or background task

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background) topic which describes `SocketActivityTrigger`